# Central AC Is not Cold

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

My AC will turn on but will not blow out cold. I'm rebuilding the whole system, ductwork and all.

I've shorted the thermostat's red (power), yellow (a/c compressor), and green (fan) wires together. The handler and compressor are both running. However, the system blows out room-temperature air.

What could be the issue? I haven't run the system for over a year, so it could have gone bad at any time really. Only thing I can think of, is that possibly the refrigerant is low, but I have no idea how to check it. The insulated refrigerant line doesn't seem to be getting cold. The compressor and interior of the handler are mostly clean - a little dirt/dust, but I doubt that it'd totally starve the system.

Is there a way to narrow down my search some more?

Comment: Are you sure the compressor's running? Maybe just the condenser fan above the compressor is.

Comment: It sounded like it was, giving a distinct "brrbrrbrrbrr" noise, and felt like it was vibrating. But maybe it was just the condensor fan making all the noise and motion. Is there a way to isolate and check the compressor?

Comment: Do you have an AMP meter?

Comment: Yes, I also have most other electric/hvac tools

Comment: You have probably already checked capacitors but if you haven't that's one of the more common failure points with whole house ac.

Comment: When you think the compressor  is running clamp your amp meter on one of the compressor leads and see if you get the nameplate reading.

Comment: @HoneyDo Thanks for the suggestion. The capacitors are working because the condensor fan is turning on. Jack: the compressor is pulling the correct amperage. Turns out it was the refrigerant, i called an hvac guy and he came and refilled for me. All good, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing, if you don't know what you're doing with respect to an HVAC system, then please call a licensed professional.  There is the potential for injury to yourself and others if you do the wrong thing.  It's also illegal to handle many refrigerants without a license in many locations.

Comment: I've taken the literal entire system apart so I know it inside and out. I've seen inside handler, read way too much documentation on my system, re-ran all the electric, gutted and re-run all the duts, set up the handler myself... maybe famous last words, but I'm pretty sure I can handle it. I'm just looking to diagnose - if I find out i need a refrigerant refill, I don't mind calling a guy to come refill it. But I'd like to save myself the money and diagnose if i can.

Comment: There is no dipstick to check the refrigerant level.  You attach a set of HVAC gauges to the high and low-side ports, read the pressures, calibrate the readings according to the temperature, and validate your measurements against what they should be.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't make refrigerant checking easy because it's suppose to be done by a licensed professional and the stuff can kill you.